# Which Plug-in Version Comes After 1.17.0

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, osgi-bundle

This might be a bit of a weird question, so bear with me.

I've got a Tycho/Eclipse plug-in that only contains a lib folder containing a third-party-library. The library has version 1.17.0, so in an attempt to make the process more transparent, the plug-in has, too.

It exports all the packages of the lib and everything is fine. At least it was, because now I realized it would have been much, much better if I exported the packages with a version. Plug-in 1.17.0 is already released (I know, Tycho doesn't normally release, just assume I don't want to re-use a version that has been stable for a year).

As an [OSGi bundle](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Bundle-Version), I am not allowed to take the version 1.17.0.1 or 1.17.0B or something, but I can't just use the version 1.17.1, because it would imply the third-party library is 1.17.1 as well, and it isn't. Updating the third-party library is not possible at the moment, because time is critical.

I tried 1.17.01 just now and nobody complains, but I'm not sure how Maven and OSGI sort this version relative to 1.17.0 and 1.17.1. [The Maven manual does not really talk about zeros](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm), but I guess it would force the string comparison, yielding in completely screwed up version sorting.

So... what version can I use safely?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use something like "1.17.0.p1" which indicates a "patch 1" - it should be ok with `OSGi` as "the qualifier can be any string, sorted lexicographically" (quote taken from your OSGi link). "p1" is similar to qualifiers like "beta1" or "RC1" or...

> major.minor.micro.qualifier

This should work for `Maven` as well. Moreover, we can assume that you would not provide a series of more than ten patches (at least I assume).

Personally, I would avoid leading zeros, as this looks quite odd to me. A series of HotFix or Patch versions should lead to an increment of a higher version number once in a while.

Comment: No, this does not work with Maven, because when trying to release I get: "You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list." Maven needs the version to end with "-SNAPSHOT".

Comment: but how do projects like Spring or Hibernate release their artifacts with ".GA" or ".Final" in their names? their must be a way to achieve this via Maven.

Comment: It is, but it's like a company-wide setting, I'd feel really bad if I had to change it for something so insignificant. Also our environment (Maven, Jenkins, Nexus, no idea who exactly) does not distinguish `1.17.0.timestamp` from `1.17.0.secondTry`, because it normally doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Tycho but the OSGI framework treats the first three parts of the version as numbers and converts them to `int` using `Integer.parseInt` (see `org.osgi.framework.Version`).

So '01' will be treated exactly the same as '1'.

Comment: That isn't that bad, they ARE identical (save for the versioned packages).

Comment: This is bad because you won't be able to distinguish the two versions if you put them into a p2 repository.

Answer (score 0):

For the new bundle version, you need to make sure that is is larger in terms of the OSGi semantics - the Maven semantics don't really matter here. So you either need to increase the numeric value of one of the first three segments (e.g. `1.17.1`) or add a fourth segment. The fourth segment, the so-called qualifier, is a string, and OSGi considers a version with qualifier to be larger than the same version without a qualifier. So you could e.g. use `1.17.0.a`.

---

One word of warning for the change that you want to introduce with the new bundle version, which is to add versions to the exported packages. It absolutely makes sense to export the packages with a version, but is is crucial that you pick the right version for the packages.

Experience has shown that **using the library version as package version is a bad idea**: When we built an OSGi wrapper for javax.mail 1.4.1, we also used the version 1.4.1 for the exported packages. But when Sun released javax.mail as OSGi bundle in version 1.4.2, they decided that the packages fulfill the 1.4 API contract and hence exported them as version 1.4. So our older version of the library pretended that its exported packages were better, and the OSGi resolve would therefore prefer it over the newer library version.

To make things worse, we in the meantime also had lots of other bundles that required the javax.mail packages with a minimum version of 1.4.1, so they couldn't even be forced to use the newer library version. In the end, it took us more than a year to clean up the mess we had gotten ourselves with the bad choice of package version in the OSGi wrapper.

Conclusion: Only **use very small package version numbers when converting a library that you don't own** to an OSGi bundle. When using package version numbers with zero as major version, e.g. 0.1.17, you should be on the safe side that the versions that you invented yourself are smaller than all future "official" version.

Comment: I don't see any way around exporting packages with versions, since any self-respecting bundle imports packages with versions. Since per default packages get exported as version ''0.0.0'', they can't be imported by anything else.